# jquery sortable dragging but not sorting itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm creating an interactive menu, in which people will use a JSON string input a list of links, which will in turn be sortable and turned into a cookie to remember the sort value. I'm just getting the general html, javascript and css frame done then i will look to port it to a plug in.

when my edit button is clicked I can drag my sortable object to and move it. however releasing it does not keep its new position. Nor do the other items 'shift across' when hovered over like the normal sortable functionality expected.

I havent worked with much of Jquery UI. so im not too familiar with it, i'm pretty sure im missing something obvious.

JS

```
 $(".menu-bar-item").sortable({
                axis: "x",
                cursor: "move",
                opacity: 0.5
            });
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu-bar">
            <li class="menu-bar-item ui-state-default" id="twitter">
                <a href="http://twitter.com" class="menu-bar-link">
                    <img class="menu-bar-image" src="/demo-icons/twitter.png" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-bar-item ui-state-default">
                <a href="#" class="menu-bar-link">
                    <img class="menu-bar-image" src="http://placehold.it/75" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-bar-item ui-state-default">
                <a href="#" class="menu-bar-link">
                    <img class="menu-bar-image" src="http://placehold.it/75" />
                </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pk27226e/

Comment: You should activate the sortable on the parent, not the child. So, `$('#menu-bar').sortable();`

Comment: -.- Wow.
give me an answer and ill confirm it... what an idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of firing the sortable plugin on the individual items, execute it on the parent list, so that get sorted, instead of the items' "children".

```
$('#menu-bar').sortable();
```

That will get the sortability on the correct elements.